Can refraction change a wave's frequency?
Can refraction change a wave's frequency under any circumstances ?
If yes, what conditions must apply for this to occur ?
Is this a common phenomenon or only happening in extreme circumstances (such as at quantum scale) ?
Please give examples.
The diagram below suggests refraction doesn't normally produce a change of frequency:

source: https://lightcolourvision.org/diagrams/refraction-of-a-wave-of-light/

Just for information, this is what led me to ask this question:
Bill Nye the Science Guy says that "different layers in the ocean that form with different temperatures and salinity" could change the detected frequency of black box pinger signals, which are nominally transmitted at a frequency of 37.5 kHz:

« As an engineer, I would say, if you have this datum from a couple of years ago where the Air France pinger changed frequency at great
depth, it's very reasonable this one did too. And as I mentioned
earlier, and I ran some numbers, and it seemed like with all the
errors, it's very reasonable that the pinger would change frequency
like this. […] And also, along with the errors introduced by the
different layers in the ocean that form with different temperatures
and salinity. » (source: CNN)


The wave source controls the frequency.  Different media change wave speed and wavelength, but the frequency remains constant per the equation $\frac{v}{\lambda} = f$.

@DavidWhite That's an answer, not a comment

Are you asking about optics/electromagnetics or about acoustics? Your image refers to optics, but the black box "pinger" was presumably producing sound, not light. (37.5 kHz is an audio frequency in the upper range of human perception, but wouldn't be a convenient frequency for a small RF transmitter to produce).

Can you provide a link to where your quote is from? I don't see it on the linked Aviation SE Q&A.

Voted to close; there are many links given, but the most important one, the quotation from which we might work out the context, is missing. Try to give useful links.

@the-photon: The quote is sourced. Click on the word "says". I'll add another link at the end of the quote.

@naturallyInconsistent : The quote is sourced. But there is NO context to my question, because the question is general.

@ "Are you asking about optics/electromagnetics or about acoustics? Your image refers to optics, but the black box "pinger" was presumably producing sound, not light.": The question says: "under any circumstances". I'm asking about waves in general. If acoustic waves behave differently with regards to refraction, then please elaborate in an answer. Thank you.

Under ANY circumstances? Sure... Doppler effect on moving objects.

@summerrain, OK, at first glance it's hard to see that "says" is a separate link from "Bill Nye the Science Guy". Maybe anchoring the first link to only "Bill Nye" would give some separation.

@the-photon : you can also click on "CNN"

No, refraction does not change the frequency.  You can understand why the frequency must remain constant by considering the fact that the waves at the boundary must be continuous. If the frequency on one side of the boundary was different than the frequency on the other side, then the waves on each side of the boundary would be out of sync which would cause discontinuities.
I don't know what Bill Nye is talking about, unless maybe the conditions of the ocean have an effect on the electronics of the pinger which causes it to change frequency.

Thank you for your answer. I don't doubt its veracity, but I don't understand its explanation. I'll make a comparison which has nothing to do with refraction: When a sound wave hits a wall, the sound on the other side is not only quieter but also altered (e.g. muffled), so not only the wave's amplitude changes but also its frequency. I don't know whether or not you consider this "out of sync", but there would be different frequencies on either side of the wall, right? So why would this be possible in my example but not in yours?

The sound example is complicated by the fact that any actual sound you hear has many different frequencies, and not all of the frequencies are softened to the same degree.  So for example if you have only two frequencies, and the higher frequency is softened more by the wall than the lower frequency, then it might sound to you that the overall frequency has decreased.  If you play a monotone sound on one side of the wall, it will still be the same monotone on the other side.

You mean the frequency of a pure tone would not change on the other side of the wall ?

Correct, the frequency of a pure tone would not change on the other side of the wall.

There's very little to go on here, even after reading the complete transcript, because Nye wasn't given very much time to explain himself. But I'll try to interpret his comments as best I can:

if you have this datum from a couple of years ago where the Air France pinger changed frequency at great depth,

I don't believe Nye is trying to say that the frequency was changed by refraction. More likely, the characteristics of the source (the pinger device itself) could be changed due to the pressure at a great depth. For example because of an out-of-spec pressure on the transducer.

And also, along with the errors introduced by the different layers in the ocean that form with different temperatures and salinity.

I don't believe this refers to errors in frequency. These factors could cause errors in estimating the depth of the pinger or its position.
As other answers have said, refraction doesn't change the frequency of the wave, because the oscillating variable (sound pressure, electric field, ..., depending on the kind of wave) is continuous across the refracting boundary.
In the case of the underwater pinger, it's possible the sound wave frequency was changed by motion of the water the wave is travelling through, but I don't see any explicit reference to this possibility in Nye's comments.
Conceivably dynamic changes in the thickness of the "different layers" in the ocean could produce temporary changes in the received signal frequency, but (without doing any calculations to check) I would expect this effect to be very small.

The wave source controls the frequency. Different media change wave speed and wavelength, but the frequency remains constant per the equation $\frac{v}{λ}=f$.
